# Optimize computation distance of million points to lines in Python

Tags: python, distance, geopandas, optimization

I have found questions here of how to compute the distance of a point to a line (manually, with distance method of some libraries...) but my problem is that I need to compute the distance of 4M points to 9K lines, and keep points that are closer than a specific distance.  I'm doing it with Python 3.5

```
    for i in range(len(multip)): #Shapely Multipoint object
        while j < len(network): # .shp file opened GeoDataFrame object from geopandas
            dist = network[j].distance(multip[i])
            print('dist', dist)
            if (dist <= critdist):
                count += 1
                xxx = (multip[i].x)
                yyy = (multip[i].y)
                distlist = np.append(distlist, dist)
                critcoordx = np.append(critcoordx, xxx)
                critcoordy = np.append(critcoordx, yyy)
                j = 0
                break
            j += 1
        j = 0
```

I couldn't come up with a solution to vectorize this process.

I also tried things like:

```
network.distance(multip)
```

But it does not compute individual distances.

Comment: Do you need the exact distances or just the criterium "closer than X"? If so you could create a buffer around the lines and just keep the points intersecting with that buffer.

Comment: Just closer than. I tried the "GIS aproach" with QGIS at the beginning, but I was facing problems of "Invalid geometry" which I couldn't fix even with validity checker and v.clean. But maybe you know another approach to do the buffering and intersection.

Comment: Maybe you still need a solution I suggest you to use the spatial indexes of [rtree](http://toblerity.org/rtree/). They could speed up a lot your script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loops are expensive, and the way you are implementing them with indices and counters adds to the execution time. Simply cleaning up the code using list comprehensions and lambda functions can make a noticeable difference. There may be further optimizations, but I am not a software engineer.

I implemented your code and got the following benchmarks:
1.25 ms ± 6.89 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

I cleaned up the code, using lambda functions and list comprehensions and got the following benchmarks: 
0.52 ms ± 55.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

Here is the code I used:

```
import geopandas
import shapely
import np as np

nPts = 10
nLines = 5
critdist = 0.05

pointCoordinates = np.random.rand(nPts,2)
multiPoint = shapely.geometry.MultiPoint(pointCoordinates)

lineCoordinates = [((each[0], each[1]), (each[2], each[3]))for each in np.random.rand(nLines, 4)]
multiLine = shapely.geometry.MultiLineString(lineCoordinates)

# My version of your code
distlist = np.array([])
critcoordx = np.array([])
critcoordy = np.array([])
count = 0
j = 0
for i in range(len(multiPoint)): #Shapely Multipoint object
    while j < len(multiLine): # .shp file opened GeoDataFrame object from geopandas
        dist = multiLine[j].distance(multiPoint[i])
        if (dist <= critdist):
            count += 1
            xxx = (multiPoint[i].x)
            yyy = (multiPoint[i].y)
            distlist = np.append(distlist, dist)
            critcoordx = np.append(critcoordx, xxx)
            critcoordy = np.append(critcoordy, yyy)
            break
        j += 1
    j = 0


# Using lamda functions and list comprehensions
def plt(point, multiLine, threshold):
    for line in multiLine:
        dist = point.distance(line)
        if dist<critdist:
            return (point.x, point.y, dist)
    return False

lt = [each for each in list(map(lambda x: plt(x, multiLine, critdist), multiPoint)) if each != False]
critCoordx = np.array([tup[0] for tup in lt])
critCoordy = np.array([tup[1] for tup in lt])
distList = np.array([tup[2] for tup in lt])
```